# JavaScript : Fastest way to itterate over elements of collection

Tags: javascript, excel, data-structures, lodash

I am currently pulling data from excel which I then push into an object of array.
I am doing so unsing lodash. My code looks like the following :

```
  Output = [];
_.forEachRight(data, element => {

    obj = { 
    MyDate: element.Date,
    Cost: element.Cost,
   
    }
    
    Output.push(obj);


});
data = Output;
```

This takes 27000 milliesseconds for a excel dataset with over 200k entries.
My question : Is there a faster way of doing the above. I dont need to use arryas so every other
data structure is welcomed.

Comment: `data = data.map(el => ({ MyDate: element.Date, Cost: element.Cost })).reverse()`

Comment: 27 secs is a lot of time to iterate through 200k of elements. Are you sure there's no DOM manipulation included?

Comment: The way you're looping through the data is extremely unlikely to make a difference. It would appear that accessing the elements and/or the `Date` and/or `Cost` properties on those elements is a slow operation. Changing how you're looping won't help that. That said, the way @CherryDT shows (`map`) would be much more idiomatic for this operation, **if** the original `data` is an array.

Comment: Thank you for clarification @T.J.Crowder. If accessing the elements is causing this. How would we get faster operation.

Comment: We'd need more details to be able to help you with that. What `data` is, where it comes from, how all of this relates to Excel, ...

Comment: @CherryDT could you explain, how and why the operation that you are showing is faster than my operation. Giving the coditions mentioned are matched.